# List all files having perl in shebang line

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find all the files having perl in the shebang line. I'm using the command `find . -type f -exec head -1 -v {} \; | grep -lR "perl"` but this is not working.

Comment: Why do you think this should work? `head` does not report the file name. So `grep` can either.

Comment: @ceving i'm using -v with head. I think that lists the files

Comment: Then add the option `-B 1` to grep. This means, print one line before the match.

Comment: @Ayush : What exactly do you mean by _is not working_?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell `find` to print the name of the file together with the first line of the file in just one line:

```
find . -type f -printf '%f: ' -exec head -n 1 {} \; |
grep perl
```

Or better:

```
find . -type f -printf '%f: ' -exec head -n 1 {} \; |
grep ':.*perl'
```

Because the first will also find files with "perl" just in the name but not in the contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -exec file "{}" + | grep -i perl
```

This won't barf on binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` to only inspect the first line:

```sh
find . \
  -type f \
  -exec awk 'NR == 1 && /^#!.*perl/ { exit } { exit 1 }' {} \; \
  -print
```

<sup>The regex can be tweaked of course.</sup>